# How can I fix this JSON file?

Tags: angularjs, json

I want to create a JSON file which consists in this format: for each **course** name there are some **categories** and for each category there are some other **details**. My JSON file looks like:

```
[
   {
      "$id":"1",
      "name":"Business"{
      "cat":"CuberSecurity"{
         "img":"img3_1.jpg",
      "cat_kurs":"7-course specialization",
      "txt":"Rice University"
      },
    "cat":"Google Cloud Platform for Systems Operations"{
       "img":"img3_2.jpg",
      "cat_kurs":"6-course specialization",
      "txt":"University of California"
    }
      }
   },
   {
      "$id":"2",
      "name":"Computer Science"{

      "cat":"Fundamentals of Computing"{
      "img":"img3_1.jpg",
      "cat_kurs":"7-course specialization",
      "txt":"Rice University"
      },
      "cat":"Data Structures and algorithms"{
      "img":"img3_2.jpg",
      "cat_kurs":"6-course specialization",
      "txt":"University of California"
      },
      "cat":"Probabilistic Graphical Models"{
       "img":"img3_3.jpg",
      "cat_kurs":"3-course specialization",
      "txt":"Stanford University"
      },
      "cat":"Bioinformatics"{
      "img":"img3_4.jpg",
      "cat_kurs":"7-course specialization",
      "txt":"University of California"
      },
      "cat":"Algorithms"{
      "img":"img3_5.jpg",
      "cat_kurs":"4-course specialization",
      "txt":"Stanford University"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I have seen it in an editor and I know it is full of mistakes. Please give me any idea how can I correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend starting out with only a couple of lines and expanding it if the synxtax is correct, there are a lot of sites that can help you with this. Just google json online validator.

edit: small example:

```
[{
    "$id": "1",
    "name": "Business",
    "cat": 
    [{
        "cname": "CyberSecurity",
        "img": "img3_1.jpg",
        "cat_kurs": "7-course specialization",
        "txt": "Rice University"
    }, {
        "cname": "Google Cloud Platform for Systems Operations",
        "img": "img3_2.jpg",
        "cat_kurs": "6-course specialization",
        "txt": "University of California"
    }]
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a [**JSON validator**](http://jsonlint.com/) when you are trying to create a JSON structure, is it really useful.

I fixed your JSON here:

```
[
   {
      "$id":"1",
      "name":"Business",
      "cat":[
         {
            "name":"CuberSecurity",
            "img":"img3_1.jpg",
            "cat_kurs":"7-course specialization",
            "txt":"Rice University"
         },
         {
            "name":"Google Cloud Platform for Systems Operations",
            "img":"img3_2.jpg",
            "cat_kurs":"6-course specialization",
            "txt":"University of California"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "$id":"2",
      "name":"Computer Science",
      "cat":[
         {
            "name":"Fundamentals of Computing",
            "img":"img3_1.jpg",
            "cat_kurs":"7-course specialization",
            "txt":"Rice University"
         },
         {
            "name":"Data Structures and algorithms",
            "img":"img3_2.jpg",
            "cat_kurs":"6-course specialization",
            "txt":"University of California"
         },
         {
            "name":"Probabilistic Graphical Models",
            "img":"img3_3.jpg",
            "cat_kurs":"3-course specialization",
            "txt":"Stanford University"
         },
         {
            "name":"Bioinformatics",
            "img":"img3_4.jpg",
            "cat_kurs":"7-course specialization",
            "txt":"University of California"
         },
         {
            "name":"Algorithms",
            "img":"img3_5.jpg",
            "cat_kurs":"4-course specialization",
            "txt":"Stanford University"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Answer (score -1):

I have another small example, a little different.

```
{
  "courses": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "categories": [
        {
          "cat_id": "1",
          "name": "Advanced Science",
          "date": "1234"
        },
        {
          "cat_id": "2",
          "name": "Advanced Math",
          "date": "1234"
        },
        {
          "cat_id": "3",
          "name": "Advanced History",
          "date": "1234"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "categories": [
        {
          "cat_id": "1",
          "name": "Advanced Science",
          "date": "1234"
        },
        {
          "cat_id": "2",
          "name": "Advanced Math",
          "date": "1234"
        },
        {
          "cat_id": "3",
          "name": "Advanced History",
          "date": "1234"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```